# Who gets the candy

Tags: halacha-theory

My wife had a situation in her class today and I was wondering what the din would be.
Girl A (5 year old) pulls a candy out of her bag. Girl B (also 5 year old) says it’s her candy. We know that girl B had this style candy and she claims she lost hers and this one is it. Girl A says she doesn’t know how it got into her bag but it’s her candy.

Here are my thoughts. On one hand I would say that since girl A is holding it despite not really having a claim, she has has chazaka and we allow her to keep it. Also she could have lied and said she got it from anywhere and we could not have disproven her (מגו) Additionally even if girl B lost her candy who says this one is it. On the other hand girl acknowledges that she has no idea how it got into her bag and so doesn’t really have a claim to it.  And so if girl B says that this one is hers and it must have fallen out of her bag into the other girls (a real possibility) she has a definite claim (bari) and so we should take it from A and give it to B.

Thoughts?

(my wife found a solution that left both kids happy)

Comment: Naska Reb Abba?

Comment: Sounds like hamotzi michaveiro alav haraya

Comment: "Girl A says she doesn’t know how it got into her bag but it’s her candy." - Why? On what basis?

Comment: @pcoz she’s a 5 year old and the candy was in her bag.

Comment: @mroll So then the question is, if a five year old is *to'en stam* on the basis of a *chezkas metaltelin* in a case where that *ta'anah* would not be considered reasonable for an adult, is that valid?